# Comando equivalente ao Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors no asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net-core

Existe uma forma de retornar um erro no asp net core somente para uma determinada action sem usar a página de custom errors?
Eu utilizava `Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors=true;` mas no ASP.Net Core não existe mais.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe sim. Uma forma simples de se exibir mensagem de erro ao usuário é utilizando a coleção **TempData**, que tem como função armazenar dados temporários que podem ser utilizados em solicitações subsequentes. (Obs. você pode baixar o projeto no GitHub pelo link  https://github.com/mpaulohs/AspNetCorePnotify )

Vamos ver como fica na prática:

1- Crie um ASP.NET Core Web Application. Selecione **File > New > Project.**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
2- Crie um classe Cliente
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

3- Crie um ViewComponent PnotifyMensagens
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

4 - Add ViewComponent no arquivo Layout.cshtml. 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

5- Crie um Action Create Cliente.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]